# Will a-b(=100) compile in C#?

Tags: c#, compilation

```
using system;

class Program
{
public static void main()
 {
  int a = 200,b;
  a-(b=100);
 }
}
```

Does the above program give out an error? If so then why? I am not in an environment where I can execute the code.

Comment: b does not have a type declaration?

Comment: You officially win the award for "Most Vague Title, Ever".

Comment: @Cody Please feel free to edit my title.

Comment: Is it possible for the OP to edit the answers?

Comment: @abcd: Yes, it is. You don't need approval or anything to do so. Click on the edit link just underneath the tags.

Comment: Are you in middle of a test? :P

Comment: @Ravi LOL, No................

Comment: But isn't it kind of not valid, howcome it executes in C even, I've never come across such operator, I am new to programming though :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check even without a <sub><sup>(local)</sup></sub> compiler:

http://ideone.com/m3qJ2

> prog.cs(8,4): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Here's the closest I got to compiling your code - http://ideone.com/FPZJq:

```
using System;

class Program
{
public static void Main()
 {
  int a = 200,b;
  int c = a-(b=100);
 }
}
```

Errors:

- `a-(b=100)` isn't a valid statement in C#. Many languages allow such empty statements (like `2;`), but not this one.
- `using system;` should be written as `using System;`
- `main` should be written as `Main`

To answer your question: your code doesn't give a *runtime* error - it isn't even valid. It does, however, give several **compilation** errors.

Comment: Thanks , the online  compiler will come in handy

Comment: Thanks , for pointing out errors in typing , I always forget to make them UpperCase.

Comment: Hey in java we write `Main` or `main` ?

Comment: @abc - Java is using `main`. These are different *conventions* - in C# the first letter of methods is in capital case, and in Java is isn't. e.g. `toString` in Java vs. `ToString` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `a - (b = 100)` is not a valid statement and hence the code will not compile.

Comment: Are you sure it won't compile?, brackets are evaluated first , so at the end it should be a- 100, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Even `a - 100` is not a valid statement. So that won't compile either.

Comment: Hmm, you are right , unless I assign it to a variable it will give out an error.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile. `a-(b=100);` is not a valid statement because:

"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: You just copied the whole line from a PDF which I am also referring :P, or maybe thats the error the compiler produces

Answer (score 2):

It gives this compiler error on the second line in the method, as you have an expression that you try to use as a statement:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

If you assign the value of the expression to a variable, it compiles:

```
a = a - (b = 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

a-(b=100)

> This does compile and work without any
>   error in C and C++ both, just tried it
>   out.

I ain't into C# so can't say about that for pretty sure but believe me in C,C++ NO ERROR OR WARNING at all, just compiles and works fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out in C, C++... +1

Answer (score 0):

I think at least it will give the error: variable b is not defined.